# Make scrollbar appear inside div

Tags: html, css

I can't find a clear answer on the following:

I have this html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title blabla</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="gHeader">
    </div>
    <div id="gBody">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

gHeader is the header part, this is where the menu goes, gBody is the body part, this is where everything else goes.

When I get a lot of content in gBody, more than can fit on the screen, a scrollbar appears on the right. Problem is that this scrollbar pushes gHeader a bit to the left.

The solution I'm searching for is that when a scrollbar appears, it only appears in gBody, and not partly on gHeader.

I don't want a scrollbar to influence the look and feel of my header. Especially because a part of my menu starts from the right. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to manually set the height of the content area, and use `overflow:auto`. Something like this might work:

```
#gHeader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; height: 150px;
}
#gBody {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; top: 150px; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: The `position: fixed;` don't make sense at all here.

Comment: That does not make any sense. Giving position fixed to an element will make it float. I know that this should not be the case in this scenario because it is **something this user is trying to avoid**. Subsequently, it has no use at all and a static position is desired. Static positions are *default* so you do not need to change anything. I know that what you want is something that works on all screen resolutions, but I do not think that is what the TS wants. If he does, I will remove my down vote. **Edit**: removed my down vote, because your solution is as good as any.

Comment: @BramVanroy Actually, this is the only way to do what ProgrammerAtWork's asking for without using javascript

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need is a fixed height and `overlow-y;` auto; on your `gBody`.

Example:

```
#gBody {
    height: 600px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Same problem here as with the iframe.. What if the total height of the site is bigger than the screen? Then you end up with 2 scrollbars

Comment: @Tom: True. I thought TS was looking for something like this, with a fixed height for the most common resolutions. If this is not what he wants, he'll need to go with Kolink's solution. :)